# C: Modify global array inside threads

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, pointers, binary-tree

I'm making a program that creates a binary tree of threads that have acces to an unique array of integers. The array is made in the main body and is modify by the threads inside the function.

The struct of the arguments for the threads is :

```
typedef struct data{
    int *array; //Pointer to the global array
    int others;
}DATA
```

In the main body I have something like:

```
main(){

   int a[18]= {1,3,4,5,6,8,6,5,4,3,5,6,2,5,7,4,5,8};
   struct data  *data = malloc(sizeof(data));
   data->array = a;
   function(data);
}
```

The function, which is recursive, generates two threads and I want to copy the adress of the array in the childs

```
function((void*)firstdata){
    pthread_t leftson;
    pthread_t rightson;
    struct data *data = firstdata;
    struct data  *dataleft = malloc(sizeof(data));
    struct data  *datarigh = malloc(sizeof(data));
    dataleft->array = data->array
    dataright->array = data -> array; 

    int i;
    printf( "\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 18; i++){
            printf( " %d ",*(dataleft->array+i));
    }
    printf( "\n"); //Print array through son

    pthread_create(&leftson,NULL,function,(void *)dataleft);
    pthread_create(&righttson,NULL,function,(void *)dataright);
}
```

This is where i get errors because of the pointer, if i try to print using the left son I get a segmentation fault without printing anything, if I try it with the right son, it prints the array and then get an error, and if I don't print at all, the function runs till the ens without errors.

I need help to understand how to manipulate the array.

I have also tried using `malloc()`when creating the array without good results.

NOTE: this code is for demostration,if tried to run, will lead to infinite loop.

Comment: You don't have threads in what you posted (and it won't compile, there are syntax errors). Please post some real code that can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hint: Using the same name for a structure (`struct data`) and a variable (`data`) is technically legal but bad practice.  What do you think the value of `sizeof(data)` is?  Is it the size of the structure or the size of the (pointer) variable?

Comment: You have infinite recursion, which will crash when the stack overflows.

Comment: I know it is an infinite recursion, I just dont want to show the full code unless is necesary, in this case the problems are the pointers.

Comment: You don't have to show your original code, but considering this code won't compile, it's untested as written and may not reproduce your issue. You should post the complete source of the minimal code that reproduces the issue. Aside from that, have you tested that the pointers passed to threads point to the same struct holding your original array?

Comment: And do take Adam's comment seriously, those `sizeof`s are terrible with those names.

Comment: Thank you @AdamRosenfield, the problem was in fact the same name for the variable  and the structure